# Layout problems with 9-patch background image

Tags: android, image, layout, background, resize

I have a 9-patch background image for my layout and it works fine when the display resoluton is smaller then the image (800x480px). But when I test it on a device with a bigger resoluton, for example 1280x800px, than the layout is broken. Here are two pictures:

[The normal and broken layout](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61662712/layout_broken.jpg)

[The 9-patch image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61662712/chalkboard.9.png)

Here is the relevant layout-code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/chalkboard"
android:gravity="top|center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

All in all, the 9-patch doesn't work when the image scales up. But what's the reason and how can I handle it?

Best regards!

Comment: in which folder you put this image ?

Comment: the 9-patches are in ldpi, mdpi and hdpi. I don't have a image for xhdpi, because of OutOfMemory problems.

Comment: the problem is with your image, you should stretch the corners border not the content

Comment: These links no longer work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stretching the frame as well. Just don't stretch the frames on the side. This should do the work: 
[image]